# Run multiple python subprocesses as a different user, only escalating privileges once

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, su

I have a python script that needs to run as a specific user.  So the first thing it does is check the user and `su`'s to the proper user before continuing.  However, future uses of `subprocess.run` are still run as the original user.

In the console, the user is switched, but the remaining stuff can't be seen until I `exit` from the user I switched to.

Here's the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

REQD_USER = "someuser"

user = subprocess.run(['whoami'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
if user.stdout != REQD_USER:
    print("Changing user to: " + REQD_USER)
    subprocess.run(['su', REQD_USER], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    # successfully switches users here
    subprocess.run(['whoami'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The last `subprocess` line doesn't print to console until I `exit` from the user I switched to and return to the original user, and prints the original user.

How can I switch to another user (assuming I have their password) and continue to run commands in the shell as the new user, without sudo?

Comment: Each subprocess is... well... just that, a separate subprocess. It sounds like what you want is to implement an IPC protocol to have your subprocess running as a different user run commands for you; doing so is the same as... well, any other IPC implementation.

Comment: That said, *why* `su`? It's a poor choice for the job. You really, **really** don't want to be in the business of driving an interactive shell, as down that path lies heuristics to try to guess at boundaries between your subprocesses; serious bugs when programs daemonize or fork off subprocesses that output to the FIFO you're sharing with output with subbsequently-invoked code, etc; it's much saner to have a Python subprocess running as the destination user with a well-defined protocol for communicating with it (asking it to do things and reading the result).

Comment: I guess what I need then is just to be able to use subprocess as a specific user?

Comment: Would it be accurate to retitle this "Run multiple subprocesses as a different user, only escalating privileges once"? (Right now, the way it's asked, only an answer that uses `su` is responsive, but I'm not sure I understand that to be the core of your use case). Also -- do you need to be able to stream results, or just to retrieve (stdout, stderr, returncode) when a process is done?

Comment: ...frankly, if you only want to run one subprocess at a time and don't need to stream output, it could be as simple as invoking a process that reads a line of JSON with `{"args": ["whoami"], "kwargs": {}}`, invokes `subprocess.Popen(*args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)` and then writes a JSON response like `{"stdout": "someuser", "stderr": "", "returncode": 0}`, repeating as long as its stdin is open. Start `sudo -u REQD_USER thatprogram.py` *once*, and then you can keep feeding it commands to run on its stdin and reading responses on its stdout indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, I think your comment about escalating once is the right one.  I don't actually need shell interactivity (other than the python script being able to read stdout stderr and returncode)